# C# Delete between two spesific character

Tags: c#, string, algorithm

Let's think we have string like below :

```
string test = 
  "I am writing something here!Developer is trying something! bla bla bla " + 
  "I am continue!Here is trying! developing."
```

I wanna get output like :

```
I am writing something here bla bla bla I am continue developing.
```

Basically, I want to *delete* between two *exclamation mark* `!`.

I tried using `Split` but it didn't work. I don't know where the exclamation point will be.

Comment: [`String.indexOf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-6.0) is one option.

Comment: Are you sure your text won't have any exclamation marks? This looks very error prone. What's the behaviour if one mark is not closed? Maybe this is homework. But you're looking for something called pushdown automaton or regex.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the content between the exclamation marks, you can use a regex to replace *!{anything but ! many times}!* by an empty string:

```
var input = "I am writing something here!Developer is trying something! I am continue!Here is trying! developing."
var regex = new Regex("![^!]*!");
var output = regex.Replace(input, string.Empty); // "I am writing something here I am continue developing."
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        string text = "I am writing something here!Developer is trying something! bla bla #bla I am continue!Here #is trying! developing.";
        
        // Replaces only ! marks in your code
        string output1 = Regex.Replace(text, @"[!]+", "") ;
        
        // Replaces ! and # - If you need more please add as or condition
        string output2 = Regex.Replace(text, @"[!|#]+", "") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you want to `Split` on `!` and then get rid of *odd index* (`1, 3, 5...`) chunks:

from

```
"I am writing something here!Developer is trying something! bla bla bla " + 
"I am continue!Here is trying! developing." =>
```

we have (after `Split`):

```
I am writing something here    - #0 keep (even)
Developer is trying something  - #1 drop (odd)
 bla bla bla I am continue     - #2 keep (even)
Here is trying                 - #3 drop (odd)
 developing.                   - #4 keep (even)
```

then combining even chunks back into string we obtain:

```
I am writing something here bla bla bla I am continue developing.
```

If it's your case, here is the code (`Split`, filtering with `Where` and, finally, `Concat` back to the string):

```
using System.Linq;

...

string result = string.Concat(test.Split('!').Where((s, i) => i % 2 == 0));
```